# Php openssl sign differs from python PKCS1_v1_5 sign

Tags: php

first of all I am new here and English it is not my firts language so i am very sorry for any mistakes. I need to replicate a algorithm made in python in a web system made in php. The algorithm generate a key to register modules in another system. The python code is this.

```
def _sign(pc_id, owner_id, product_id):
key_file = open('private_key.pem', 'rb')
private_key = RSA.importKey(key_file.read())
message = '{0},{1},{2}'.format(pc_id, owner_id, product_id)
message_hash = SHA256.new(base64.b64encode(message.encode('ascii')))
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
signature = signer.sign(message_hash)
return signature
```

and the php one is this:

```
        $fp = fopen("docs/private_key.pem", "r");
        $priv_key = fread($fp, 8192);
        fclose($fp);
        $pkeyid =  openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
        $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($codapp,"auto");
        $message_hash = hash("sha256",mb_convert_encoding($codapp,   "ASCII",$encoding));            
        openssl_sign($message_hash, $signature, $pkeyid);           
        openssl_free_key($pkeyid);
        $temp_return= base64_encode($signature);
        $return = mb_convert_encoding($temp_return, $encoding);
        return $return;
```

until the sign everthing it is ok, the hash is the same, but when I try to sign with the same private key from the python code the $signature give me a differnt outcome and a string full of gibberish in the form of  question marks in black and when I encode that string with base64_encode the resulting string if way diferent from the one in python. First time signing anything. I looked in google and i find several post about signing but none that could help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do not compare signatures. Just verify each signature.

Comment: Thank for your answer I use both signatures to register the product as it is intended the python signature it is ok but the php one not. I think that there is some codifications issues at sign time because i get gibberish after that, just like when ther its deifference between file enconding a browser....

Comment: All openssl functions have return codes. Always check this return code and do not proceed if the return code is not what you need. In addition if you have an openssl failure call openssl_error_string ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come out with a solution. First of all the string was'nt came in howle ' cause a field restriction from the view ergo the signature were differents :( my bad. Anyway I manage to change my code and improve it this it is how it ended.

```
        $fpr = fopen("docs/private_key.pem", "r");
        $fpu = fopen("docs/public_key.pem", "r");
        $priv_key = fread($fpr, 8192); 
        $pub_key = fread($fpu, 8192);

        fclose($fpr); 
        fclose($fpu);
        $pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);

        openssl_sign($codapp, $signature, $priv_key,"sha256WithRSAEncryption");
        $ok = openssl_verify($codapp, $signature, $pub_key,"sha256WithRSAEncryption" );
        $return = base64_encode($signature);
        return $return;
```

Rigth now the python and php signatures are the same. Thanks to the people that reply.